# Import error when using scipy.io module

Tags: python, scipy

I'm involved in a raspberry pi project and I use python language. I installed scipy, numpy, matplotlib and other libraries correctly. But when I type

from scipy.io import wavfile 
it gives error as "ImportError: No module named scipy.io"

I tried to re-install them, but when i type the sudo cord, it says already the new version of scipy is installed. I'm stucked in this point and please help me... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would take a guess and say your Python doesnt know where you isntalled scipy.io. add the scipy path to PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Thanx alot for giving me an answer..I'm new to both raspberry and python. can u please tell me how to do it? I type ma codes in IDLE3 and run the modules from that. Can you please tell me what should I do in order to give the path

Comment: using bash, in your bash profile file, you can add this line `export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/scipy:$PYTHONPATH"`